# What does the code mean? (Deleting files and sub folders in a folder with a batch file)

Tags: batch-file

```
del /s /q "C\:test\*.*"
for /d %%p in (C:\test\*.*) do rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

This is a code I have which deletes files and sub folders in a folder. And it works, but I do not get what each of the command works. So my question is, what does the second line mean? Like, what is the `%%p` part, and what is the rmdir `"%%p"` part?

This is a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

`for /d` is to iterate directories.`%%p` is a special kind of variable used in for loops - in this case it will change its value to each directory name in `c:\tests` . The part after do means execute `rmdir` (deletes directory) for each value of `%%p`. More info [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, you should see the help of each command by typing `YourCommand /?` :

**[Del /?](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)**

**[RD /? or rmdir /?](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)**

**[For /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

I added an `echo` to see what happen when you execute your batch file :

```
@echo off
Echo This command to delete all files located on your "C\:test\" folder
Echo del /s /q "C\:test\*.*"
pause
echo this command is for looping thru your directory "C\:test\" to remove any subfolders on there
for /d %%p in (C:\test\*.*) do echo rmdir "%%p" /s /q
pause
```